# Получить ID всех пользователей, лайкнувших пост максимально быстро

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хочу ежедневно видеть сводку самых активных подписчиков группы. Для того, чтобы это сделать есть очевидный выход - сделать `wall.get` перебирая, получая все посты и потом перебирать уже их через `likes.get`. Но что делать, если постов больше 10 тысяч? Не отправлять же 10 тысяч реквестов, а пользователь вполне может поставить лайк на очень древний пост. Есть ли какие-то адекватные кейсы для решения данной проблемы?